# Converting Xarray DataArray to Iris Cube

Tags: python, python-xarray, python-iris

I have a netCDF file which I have loaded as an Xarray DataArray:

```
data = xr.open_dataset('radar_data.nc')
```

I want to pull out the 'CZ' variable (radar reflectivity) and convert this to an Iris cube:

```
Z    = data['CZ']
Z_ir = Z.to_iris()
```

However, when I try this, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: 'CZ' is not a valid standard_name
```

I'm not really familiar with the Iris module at all, so I'm not really sure how to interpret that. What's going on here?

For reference, here is an example of a file I am trying to open:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rj7O-pDhlsgC8-ajG1nxEKXVxhWkFzZr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It sounds like the file is not CF-compliant. Check here https://cfconventions.org/compliance-checker.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to solve my problem by doing:

```
Z.attrs['standard_name'] = 'equivalent_reflectivity_factor'
```